# How to remove QOpenGLContext::swapBuffers() called without corresponding makeCurrent()

Tags: qt, opengl, qt-creator, qglwidget

How can I stop this warning in Qt 5.4.1 in Debug/Release mode.

```
QOpenGLContext::swapBuffers() called without corresponding makeCurrent()
```

It only appears in debug mode, but release mode is fine with VS2010.
It appears in both modes (Debug & Release) with QtCreator.

I have tried so many ways to remove it but no success, searched google but couldn't find any useful info.

Plateform: Windows 8.1- VS2010- Qt_Creator Nvidia GTX 765

Thanks.

Comment: If its not possible to remove this warning, can I stop it by giving some command to compile?

Comment: Well, the emission of that warning message is part of the code of Qt itself. When you're running a debug build of your program it's linking against the debug build of Qt, which emits this message. So other than recompiling Qt yourself, patching out that obnoxious (and BTW invalid warning) yourself there's little you can do. Qt's OpenGL interaction is at some places fundamentally broken; OpenGL contexts are tied to drawables; oh you can create a OpenGL context manually and attach that to a drawable, but as soon as that gets deleted it takes the OpenGL context with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serious answer: By filing a bug report with the Qt developers. Calling `SwapBuffers` on a drawable without a OpenGL context bound to it is perfectly fine. Actually `SwapBuffers` does not belong to the OpenGL context but to the window, so having that method placed in `QGLContext` is a big design failure itself.

---

Personal rant (in the hope some Qt devs are going to see it, eventually):

These guys (like every other toolkit developer community I got the impression) really need some summer school in how OpenGL works and what you should and should not do. I know of no toolkit that gets OpenGL context management right. If developing a toolkit wasn't such a huge amount of work I'd go "Fine, I'll develop my own GUI toolkit, with Blackjack and hookers…"

Comment: Probably because `swapBuffers()` implementation has to call `glClear()` on the window's context, no?

Comment: I don't understand, why the hell they don't allow us console, every example they made, without console. When we try to enable it. this happens.

Comment: @GreenScape: No. swapBuffers just shall swap the buffers and nothing more. If anything then glClear goes into the default paint event handler. But if a framework calls glClear on its own behalf its already broken on Sloth (the Goonies character) levels of retardation.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your code, instead of suppressing warning. You may show an SSCCE, if you want some hints from community.

But if you still want to suppress warnings, you need to follow [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/debug.html)

Comment: Qt team doesn't fix minor bugs, if they are reported by community. They care only about bugs, that are perorted by owners of professional / enterprise subscriptions.

Comment: I tried to solve this issue 1 year ago but failed, I am again stuck with it. At that time, some people already filed this a bug, but even not fixed in 5.4.1.

Comment: @furqan please, provide a link to bugreport. I'll vote for that issue.

Comment: @SaZ Don't have that link now, because it was long ago, I voted for that. Will get back if I found that.